# Performance Problem on HP EliteBook 8440p corei5

Tags: drivers, hp, performance, ram, bios

I am using HP EliteBook 8440p corei5 laptop.When I buy this laptop its processing speed is perfect but nowadays everything slowdowns on it.I amn't able to understand that what is the problem...
HD 720p videos don't run properly.
Processing issues.
I want to run Visual studio 2017 but its compiling and execution speed it too slow on my laptop.
How can I fix my laptop so that all the performance issues get resolved rather than buying a new laptop.
Laptop Specification.

```
HP EliteBook 8440p
Processor= Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU ,M 460  @ 2.53GHz, 2534 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
RAM =4GB,Hard =250GB
BIOS Version/Date   Hewlett-Packard 68CCU Ver. F.11, 11/25/2010
Window 10.
```

Comment: make a bootable ubuntu usb, see if you still suffer these slowdowns when running linux from usb, if not, there is a high chance of your OS got damaged somehow and you need a re-installation.

Comment: When I run the thing through USB.Every thing runs perfectly.I run HD videos on a laptop they didn't able to play properly sometimes show gray screen.But when I run the same video through USB it runs perfectly.Then now what you diagnose?

Comment: This means the problem lies with your OS, your hardware is alright. If you can afford a complete reinstall of OS, go for it. If that's not an option, read the system logs and try to figure out what is causing the bottleneck.

Comment: What is "complete reinstall of OS".Is it involve installation of window again.if yes I tried it much time by installing window 7 and 8 but don't get any best result.

Comment: remove windows and install ubuntu